# proc.stderr.readlines() hangs with specific svn path

Tags: python-3.x, svn, subprocess

Python 3.6.5
This is my code for listing directory in svn. It works for most directories quite well, but with one path line `error = proc.stderr.readlines()` hangs forever (100% repeatable). Any ideas why or workaround on that? From terminal command works

```
class MyRemoteSvnClient(object):
def __init__(self, url):
    self.url = url

def list(self, rel_path=None, retries=5):
    url = self.url if self.url.endswith('/') else self.url + '/'
    if rel_path:
        url = '{}{}'.format(url, rel_path)
    # print(url)
    retries = retries + 1
    for i in range(1, retries):
        proc = Popen(['svn', 'ls', url], shell=True, stdout=PIPE,
                                stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
        error = proc.stderr.readlines()
        if i == retries - 1:
            raise SvnException(error)
        if error:
            logger.warning('svn error occurred, retrying {}/{}'.format(i, retries - 1))
            sleep(1)
            continue
        while True:
            output = proc.stdout.readline().strip()
            if proc.poll() is not None:
                break
            if output:
                yield output
        break
```

Comment: So, does `svn ls` *called by hand* also hangs on the same URI?

Comment: Also: why do you expect reading from `stderr` to *not* hang in the *normal* case? AFAIK, `svn ls` is supposed to print its normal output to its `stdout`, and only ever write to `stderr` in case of an error or a warning (as all the "well-behaving" Unix programs are supposed to do); so if it outputs nothing to `stderr`, an attempt to reading from it naturally hangs. Is this your problem may be?

Comment: 1) Url is same
2) svn seems to print nothing to stderr in case of no err output and svn errors otherwise. You can normally read from empty stderr and it wont hang.